# How to get sign-in method?

Tags: google-api, credentials, google-signin

Im trying to follow [this](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/credential-management/retrieve-credentials)

In case below i get `gSignIn` not defined error,
also have `<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>` in head.

I missing some api?
How can i reach `gSignIn` method?
How i can trigger singin via js?

```
navigator.credentials.get({
    password: true,
    federated: {
        providers: [
            'https://accounts.google.com'
        ]
    },
    mediation: 'required'
}).then(c => {
    if (c) {
        switch (c.type) {
            case 'password':
                return sendRequest(c);
                break;
            case 'federated':
                return gSignIn(c);
                break;
        }
    } else {
        return Promise.resolve();
    }
}).then(profile => {
    if (profile) {
        updateUI(profile);
    }
}).catch(error => {
    console.error('Sign-in Failed');
});
```

Comment: A user has to click the login button when they want to login.  Why would you not want to?

Comment: @DalmTo browser have user credentails already because he did click button in past. Now i want to autologin, but with credentails choose popup

Comment: @DaImTo in case he lose his session or want to switch account

Comment: In either case they will have to login again wont they you wont want to guess that this is the user and someone else hasnt taken over their machine.

Comment: @DalmTo sory but i dont get what you mean, this is common behavior, simply auto login but i want user to have possibility to choose between stored credentails even if it is only one. Couse google auto login based on button works well. I have problem that i cant reach gSignIn method

Comment: @DaImTo i mean expired session on my service, not google account session.